# How to sum columns and rows in a wide R dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'd like to mutate by dataframe by summing both columns and rows.

```
mydata <-structure(list(description.y = c("X1", "X2"), `2011` = c(13185.66, 
82444.01), `2012` = c(14987.61, 103399.4), `2013` = c(26288.98, 
86098.22), `2014` = c(15238.21, 88540.04), `2015` = c(15987.11, 
113145.1), `2016` = c(16324.57, 113196.2), `2017` = c(16594.87, 
122167.57), `2018` = c(20236.02, 120058.21), `2019` = c(20626.69, 
130699.68), `2020` = c(19553.83, 136464.31), `2021` = c(10426.32, 
56392.28)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), groups = structure(list(description.y = c("X1", 
"X2"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I can sum rows like this

```
mydata1 <- mydata %>% 
      mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
```

Which provides an extra column with totals for the rows
[image]

But I'm not sure how to add Columns to the dataframe while also retaining all existing values

I've tried this but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
 mydata1 <- mydata %>% 
      mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>% 
      mutate(Total = colSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
```

Comment: If you're preparing something to display, then check out the `gt` package.  It can also do totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to first `summarize` and then `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%
  bind_rows(summarize(., description.y = "Total", across(where(is.numeric), sum)))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  description.y `2011`  `2012`  `2013`  `2014`  `2015`  `2016`  `2017`  `2018`  `2019`  `2020` `2021`    Total
  <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 X1            13186.  14988.  26289.  15238.  15987.  16325.  16595.  20236.  20627.  19554. 10426.  189450.
2 X2            82444. 103399.  86098.  88540. 113145. 113196. 122168. 120058. 130700. 136464. 56392. 1152605.
3 Total         95630. 118387. 112387. 103778. 129132. 129521. 138762. 140294. 151326. 156018. 66819. 1342055.
```

Comment: Very good solution!

Comment: Perfects - thanks for all the excellent answers - I had trouble finding these solutions. They work great! I wish I could tick both answers

Answer (score 4):

Update: See comment @Mwavu -> many thanks!
direct solution with `adorn_total()`:

```
mydata %>% adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col"))
```

First answer:
We could use `adorn_totals()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>% 
  adorn_totals()
```

```
 description.y     2011      2012      2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018      2019      2020     2021     Total
            X1 13185.66  14987.61  26288.98  15238.21  15987.11  16324.57  16594.87  20236.02  20626.69  19553.83 10426.32  189449.9
            X2 82444.01 103399.40  86098.22  88540.04 113145.10 113196.20 122167.57 120058.21 130699.68 136464.31 56392.28 1152605.0
         Total 95629.67 118387.01 112387.20 103778.25 129132.21 129520.77 138762.44 140294.23 151326.37 156018.14 66818.60 1342054.9
```

Comment: `mydata %>% adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col"))` gets the job done.

Comment: @Mwavu. Many thanks. This is new to me. Perfrect. I will update my answer!